# PreviewKeyDown not firing

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

My form won't fire `PreviewKeyDown` no matter what. The `KeyPreview` property is already set to `True`.

```
Private Sub frmMain_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles MyBase.PreviewKeyDown
    'Code never hits this line
End Sub
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Winforms wasn't exactly blessed with having to provide some degree of backwards-compatibility with VB6, the dominant GUI development tool before .NET came around.  KeyPreview is such a back-compat property, VB6 had that property as well.  In VB6 it was the only way to implement shortcut keystrokes, it raises the form's *KeyDown* event before it raises the KeyDown event on the control with the focus.  Not PreviewKeyDown.

It has some more VB6 quirks, KeyDown won't raise for navigation keys like Tab, the arrow keys and Enter and Escape.  Which is what the Winforms specific PreviewKeyDown event is all about, you can have a sniff at such a key before it performs the navigation operation.  But only on the control that has the focus which will never be the form when it has any controls.

It is certainly best to ditch this back-compat feature and use Winforms specific support for keyboard handling, cuts down on the surprises.  The best way to implement shortcut keystrokes is to override the form's ProcessCmdKey() method, it unconditionally runs regardless of the key or the state of the form:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.F1 Then
        '' Show help
        ''...
        Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Comment: This is gem of an answer. Anyone handling menu items etc. in a WinForms application should check this out.

Comment: I had some trouble to test the modifiers bits because of STRICT ON option. 
This worked for me:
        Dim i As Integer = CType(keyData, Integer)
        Dim ic As Short = CShort(i \ 65536)
        Dim ik As Short = CShort(i Mod 65536)
        If ic = 2 AndAlso ik = Keys.A Then
            Debug.WriteLine("ctrlA pressed")
        End If