# VB.net Moving a picturebox which is inside a child form using arrow keys

Tags: vb.net, arrow-keys

I have a form which is a child of a panel of the main form. There is a picture box inside this child form which i want to move using the arrow keys up/down.
I have tried the following code:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Up
            If PictureBox1.Top > Me.Top Then
                Me.PictureBox1.Top -= 1
            End If
        Case Keys.Down
            If PictureBox1.Bottom < Me.Bottom Then
                Me.PictureBox1.Top += 1
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

But the picture box is not moving probably because it is not a part of the main form but belongs to a sub form which is a child of a panel of the main form. The sub form has only three picture box in it and no other control. The child form is created dynamically using the following:

```
Dim winForm As New Form2
winForm.Parent = Me.PnlMain
```

What is the workaround to do this? anybody help.

Comment: Why would you have a form inside a `Panel`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18931895/17034